# Is making joins between different table spaces slower?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In MySQL and PostgreSQL, is making joins between different tablespaces inherently slower, compared to joining tables in the same tablespace?

Comment: mysql doesnt have tablespaces

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be slower in PostgreSQL (to the contrary, with certain setups I'd imagine it being faster to much faster) - but why not try it yourself?

Comment: @Mihai and what is this?: [`CREATE TABLESPACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-tablespace.html)

Comment: @ypercube I stand corrected,nice to know about this cluster option.

Comment: @ypercube: that is only for MySQL **Cluster**, not for a "regular" MySQL installation.

Comment: MySQL has no table spaces (or an equivalent) outside a MySQL cluster?!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true but the question is general.

Comment: @Mihai `ibdata1` is a tablespace. Every ibd and MYD file is also a tablespace, but they aren't potentially shared like ibdata1.

Answer (score 2):

This is only for Postgres:

If the tablespaces reside all on the same harddisk, then there is no performance difference at all.

If the tablespaces are created on different harddisks then yes, this can make a difference. In that case the necessary I/O is spread over multiple disks, thus improving the overall throughput (assuming all harddisks have the same performance).

Comment: Until contents of the table are cached, then it doesn't matter any more for read operations.

Comment: The question asks if different tablespaces makes it *slower*.  "Yes, this can make a difference" means *faster*, not slower... since different disks implies more I/O bandwidth... right?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, doing a JOIN between two *databases* is essentially the same speed as within the same *database*.  (The term "tablespace" is not relevant to JOINing.)  That is, these are virtually identical in performance:

```
SELECT ... FROM tblx JOIN tbly ...

SELECT ... FROM db1.tblx JOIN db2.tbly ...
```

A database is implemented as a directory; tables in the database are implemented as file(s) in the directories.  Once opened, the database that the table belongs to is mostly buried in the details.